# MacBook Pro 13 inch late 2011 flickering screen

Tags: display, screen, gpu

I have some problems with the screen of my laptop MacBook Pro 13inch from late 2011. I never had problems with my screen before but suddenly the screen began to flicker. I have encountered that it starts flickering more when my laptop is running more intensive programs whereby it is warmer than usually. When I play with the adjustments of the screen, or tap the screen the flickering comes and goes.

I do not know if it is some wire inside that is half broken so that the connection bad or if my GPU or motherboard is broken. I know that the MacBook Pro's made in 2011 had some problems with the motherboard but this was only the case for the 15 inch laptops. I also made a video to make it more clear. You can see on the video that when I tap on the part where the wires are going from the laptop to the screen, that the screen starts flickering.

Youtube link to video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gjaDSE4eDxg

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're graphic card is going to die. It's a known issue - More about that here:  https://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/

Luckily there's a free  MacBook Pro Repair Extension Program until February. You can [lookup your MacBook](https://checkcoverage.apple.com/ca/en/;jsessionid=1LBTWM8GVyvkfblntZhRV9QZ7XZLyq9g1fWShZkKyM44n11Gnwc4!-1417462048) serial number if it's covered by warranty.

Comment: Normally the 13 inch MacBooks did not have that problem, only the 15 and 17 inch. As you can see on the link you have send me

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Anyway, the logic board needs to be replaced. Thus, talk to your Apple Service Provider/Apple Store.